Cómo usar simple-oauth2 para obtener el access_token en la autenticación de Stack Overflow
Resumen
Los códigos de proyectos de fuente abierta que he tomado para autenticar (OAuth2) con cuentas de GitHub me funcionan con solo agregar el client id y el client secret, pero al intentar usar Stack Overflow incluso incluyendo el "Key" para tener cuotas de uso altas me devuelve

The content-type is not JSON compatible

Se que los datos deben enviarse como parámetros del URL. Estoy usando el "end-point" que responde con un objeto de JavaScript (usualmente referido como JSON, pero un JSON es una cadena de texto o archivo de texto plano con extensión .json.
Comando de línea a replicar
Fuente: How can I quickly get an access token for personal use?
curl -d "client_id=...&client_secret=...&code=...&redirect_uri=https://stackapps.com" -X POST https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token
Sé que getToken maneja dos parámetros de tipo Objeto, param el cual es obligatorio y httpOptions el cual es opcional.
¿Cómo debo configurar los parametros del método getToken del paquete simple-oauth2 para Node.js para obtener el access_code de la autenticación de Stack Overflow?
Repositorio en GitHub del "MCVE": https://github.com/rubenrivera/simple-oauth2-example. Abajo se incluye el código que consideré indispensable para cumplir con el requisito de que la pregunta sea autocontenida.

En https://github.com/11ty/demo-eleventy-serverless-oauth se usa el complemento Eleventy Serverless y el paquete de Node.js simple-outh2 para agregar autenticación a un sitio web con integración continua usando Netlify.
El demo incluye varios casos: Netlify, GitHub, GitLab, Slack, LinkedIn. He clonado el repositorio del demo en local, agregado el Client Id y Client Secret de GitHub como variables del entorno en Netlify y ejectuado los comandos de línea para desplegar en localhost según se indica en el README.md. Hasta aquí todo bien.
He modificado el archivo Netlify/functions/Utils/providers.js para agregar Stack Overflow como proveedor de OAuth2 siguiendo las indicaciones y repetido el procedimento para realizar el despliegue en localhost, sin embargo, en este caso ocurre un error:

content-type is not JSON compatible.

Este error ocurre en la sección del código que debería objener el access_token.
He encontrado una solución provisional usando fetch pero me gustaría saber que debería modificar para que el método getToken de simple-oauth2  funcione.
Para construir el ejemplo mínimo, completo, y verificable tomé la carpeta examples del repositorio de simple-oauth2 en GitHub. De esta forma dejo fuera lo de Eleventy Serverless ya que este no influye en el problema.
Código
.env
Nuevo
A continuación sólo se incluyen los nombres de las variables por razones de seguridad.
STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID =
STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=
STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_KEY=

stackoverflow.js
Nuevo
Este archivo es una adaptación del archivo dropbox.js. Los cambios  Se indican usando un bloque de comentarios en español.
'use strict';

const createApplication = require('./');
/** 
 * Modificación 0
 * Llamar el simple-oauth2 por nombre del paquete
 */
const { AuthorizationCode } = require('simple-oauth2');

/**
 * Modificación 1  
 * Agregar el paquete dotenv para leer los valores del nuevo archivo .env
 */
require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * Modificación 2
 * Declarar variables para el manejo de Client ID, Client Secret y Key de la aplicación registrada en https://stackapps.com, según instrucciones de https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication
 */
const clientId = process.env.STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;
const clientKey = process.env.STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_KEY;

createApplication(({ app, callbackUrl }) => {
  const client = new AuthorizationCode({
    client: {
      id: clientId,
      secret: clientSecret,
    },
    auth: {
      tokenHost: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
      authorizeHost: 'https://stackoverflow.com',
      authorizePath: 'https://stackoverflow.com/oauth',
    },
    options: {
      authorizationMethod: 'body',
    },
  });

  // Authorization uri definition
  const authorizationUri = client.authorizeURL({
    redirect_uri: callbackUrl,
    state: '3(#0/!~',
  });

  // Initial page redirecting to Github
  app.get('/auth', (req, res) => {
    console.log(authorizationUri);
    res.redirect(authorizationUri);
  });

  // Callback service parsing the authorization token and asking for the access token
  app.get('/callback', async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.query;
    const options = {
      code,
      redirect_uri: callbackUrl,
    };

    try {
      const accessToken = await client.getToken(options);

      console.log('The resulting token: ', accessToken.token);

      return res.status(200).json(accessToken.token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Access Token Error', error.message);
      return res.status(500).json('Authentication failed');
    }
  });

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello<br><a href="/auth">Log in with Stack Overflow</a>');
  });
});

package.json
Modificación: Agregar la propiedad "start:stackoverflow": "node stackoverflow/index.js" al objeto scripts.
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:github": "node github.js",
    "start:microsoft": "node microsoft.js",
    "start:dropbox": "node dropbox.js",
    "start:stackoverflow": "node stackoverflow/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "simple-oauth2": "^5.0.0"
  }
}

index.js
Modificación: Ninguna
'use strict';

const app = require('express')();

const port = 3000;

module.exports = (cb) => {
  const callbackUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/callback';

  app.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(`Express server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);

    return cb({
      app,
      callbackUrl,
    });
  });
};


Sobre la modificación provisional, la cual funciona sin problemas, en lugar de usar const accessToken = await client.getToken(options);, estoy llamando la función getToken definida de la forma siguiente:
stackoverflow/authentication.js
const tokenPath = "https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json";

const clientId = process.env.STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET;
const clientKey = process.env.STACKOVERFLOW_OAUTH_KEY;

async function getToken(code, callbackUrl){
    const obj = {
        code,
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
        redirect_uri: callbackUrl,
        key: clientKey
      };
  
  
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    Object.keys(obj).forEach( key => params.append(key, obj[key]));
  
      
    const response = await fetch(tokenPath, {method: 'POST', body: params});
    const data = await response.json();
    const accessToken = data.access_token
    console.log('The resulting token: ', accessToken);
    return accessToken;

}

module.exports = {
    getToken
}

La solución provisional está bien para salir del paso, pero estoy del todo seguro que sea la mejor forma. No es tan mala porque usa una característica incluída de Node.js version 18 y siguientes: fetch.
Actualización
Para mayor claridad de que el error ocurre en el módulo de simple-oauth2 agregué error.stack al console.log en el catch.
error.stack
Error: The content-type is not JSON compatible
    at finish (/Users/rubenrivera/Local Documents/dev/simple-oauth2-example/node_modules/@hapi/wreck/lib/index.js:401:42)
    at wrappedFn (/Users/rubenrivera/Local Documents/dev/simple-oauth2-example/node_modules/@hapi/wreck/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/once.js:19:13)
    at module.exports.internals.Recorder.onReaderFinish (/Users/rubenrivera/Local Documents/dev/simple-oauth2-example/node_modules/@hapi/wreck/lib/index.js:454:20)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:28)
    at module.exports.internals.Recorder.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:946:10)
    at node:internal/streams/writable:927:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)


Relacionado

PLACEHOLDER: Propose Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange as OAuth provider to demo-eleventy-serverless-oauth


@Yussef el código que tiene el error no tiene una variable response, usa req y res. Por otro lado, el error ocurre antes de que simple-oauth2 devuelva una respuesta. Para mayor claridad he editado la pregunta.
